Django: Base template does not render content from {% block content%} on HTML page
I am trying to use a template to be able to reuse a flexbox across multiple pages; rather than reuse the code on each page.
EDIT: *The url I hit when I run the page layout.html  from VS Code's Live Server ("Open with Live Server")is:
http://127.0.0.1:5500/Resilience_Radar_App/templates/Resilience_Radar_App/layout.html*
However, rather than getting the flexbox I get:

If I just render the html as a page to be sure the flexbox works I get the expected output:

My html templates are all located in:
/Resilience_Radar/Resilience_Radar_App/templates/Resilience_Radar_App/
I setup the layout.html file to include the stylesheet defining the container and added the templates tags:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Resilience</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Risk Resilience</h1>
{% block linesofoperation %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>

I the created a file linesofoperation.html that contained the desired code to use in the block:
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block linesofoperation %}

<div class="container" style="top: 10%;">
    
    <div class="item_LoO_Name">
      <div class="t1">LoO</div>
      <div class="t2">Implement, maintain and improve a
    business countinuity management system</div>
    </div>
    <div class="space"></div>
    <div class="item">Context of the Organization</div>
    <div class="space"></div>
    <div class="item" style = "background-color:gray">Leadership</div>
    <div class="space"></div>
    <div class="item" >Policy</div>
    <div class="space"></div>
    <div class="item">Planning</div>
    <div class="space"></div>
    <div class="item">Support</div>
    <div class="space"></div>
    <div class="item">Operation</div>
    <div class="space"></div>
    <div class="item">Management Review</div>
    <div class="space"></div>
    <div class="item">Improvement</div>
    <div class="space"></div>
    <div class="triangle-right"></div>
    <div class="spaceblank"></div>

    
    <div class="item_LoO_Name" style="background-color: white; color: black;">
      <div class="t1">Outcome</div>
      <div class="t2">Protect against, reduce the likelihood of the occurrence of, 
      prepare for, respond to and recover from disruptions when they arise</div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock linesofoperation %}

Here's my views.py
def leadership(request):
    return render(request, "Resilience_Radar_App/leadership.html")

def linesofoperation(request):
    return render(request, "Resilience_Radar_App/linesofoperation.html")

def layout(request):
    return render(request, "Resilience_Radar_App/layout.html")

and my urls.py in the app
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.leadership, name="leadership"),
    path("", views.RadioButtonForm, name="RBF"),
    path("linesofoperation/", views.linesofoperation, name = "LoO")

and in the main folder:
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("Resilience_Radar_App/", include("Resilience_Radar_App.urls"))

I was trying to get the layout.html to be the template for a number of pages that all would include the flexbox graphic with different content on each page.
One answer I found gave an error as:
Finally, I found the mistake:
I refered in my view to the "parent" file (base.html) instead of the "child" file (landingPage.html).
But no code so I am not sure what the error was.

That {% block linesofoperation %} shouldn't literally be showing up in the rendered HTML even if you somehow get the template inheritance wrong, what URL are you hitting? I believe you might be either opening the HTML file directly or serving that HTML as a static file somehow. Please [edit] your question and clarify so that we have a proper [mre].

Thanks.  I've edited it to show the url VS Studio code uses to open the page via "Open with Live Server.".  Neither of the 2 solutions worked; each simply renders the {% %} code.

The URL you're hitting doesn't look like what you should be hitting... You also say that you're using "VS Code's Live server", that is an extension to serve static sites and not meant to be used with Django, you should be running python manage.py runserver instead of that live server extension...

Thanks.  I started the sever using manage.py but didn’t realize it used a different port.  However, I must have messed up the urls because while 127.0.0.1/Reslience_Radar_App opens the first item in the urls.py file, adding anything afterward yields cannot resolve url errors.  I appreciate the help, at this point I think I’ll just use static pages while i figure this out.

You want to hit: /Resilience_Radar_App/linesofoperation/ (on the correct host and port obviously)

I had corrected the mistakes :-

the way you extends the layout html all are good but you did not load static so i have included that also in the below code just go through the code.

layout.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang = "en">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles.css' %}">
  <title>Resilience</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Risk Resilience</h1>
{% block linesofoperation %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>

linesofoperation.html
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block linesofoperation %}

<div class="container" style="top: 10%;">
    
    <div class="item_LoO_Name">
      <div class="t1">LoO</div>
      <div class="t2">Implement, maintain and improve a
    business countinuity management system</div>
    </div>
    <div class="space"></div>
    <div class="item">Context of the Organization</div>
    <div class="space"></div>
    <div class="item" style = "background-color:gray">Leadership</div>
    <div class="space"></div>
    <div class="item" >Policy</div>
    <div class="space"></div>
    <div class="item">Planning</div>
    <div class="space"></div>
    <div class="item">Support</div>
    <div class="space"></div>
    <div class="item">Operation</div>
    <div class="space"></div>
    <div class="item">Management Review</div>
    <div class="space"></div>
    <div class="item">Improvement</div>
    <div class="space"></div>
    <div class="triangle-right"></div>
    <div class="spaceblank"></div>

    
    <div class="item_LoO_Name" style="background-color: white; color: black;">
      <div class="t1">Outcome</div>
      <div class="t2">Protect against, reduce the likelihood of the occurrence of, 
      prepare for, respond to and recover from disruptions when they arise</div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock linesofoperation %}


The OP is not asking for Static files loading, The problem is with html template extension

yeah, i have edited the answer, how about the answer now @khushal
